# Is there more than one type of granularities?

Tags: sql

Give an examples of two different granularities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Customer table. That table could have a generic Name column containing "Dr Stack Overflow Jr".

Or, it could have a reference to a Name table containing Title, First name, Last name, and suffix columns.

Both schemas hold the same information, but the second option has a finer granularity. Note that finer granularity isn't always better, and neither is rougher granularity. Too fine of granularity can make interacting with the database more hassle than it should be (consider a Phone table with an individual column for each digit). On the other side of the spectrum, too coarse a granularity and you'll have to spend time parsing information (consider an Address varchar column containing Street, Apt, City, Province, Country -- you'd have to parse it every time you wanted to see what country a customer is in)

Comment: Is this not wrong? The granularity is higher the more rows are distinct. Thus, if you concatenate three columns to one, you will have a higher (=finder) granularity in that column.